# Remove white border around an ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

My designer keeps adding a little padding around my image.
I want the image the stick on the top and to fill out the width of the screen.

Here's a screenshot from the designer:

[image: Screenshot]

This is my XML code:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/markertap_header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/header_bootsverleih_xhdpi" />
```

Comment: If the white border is in the image itself, you should crop the image manually once rather than trying to alter it every time the app is run.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Experienced the same when I used an ImageView for Splashscreen, this^ worked for me.

Comment: This answer is much better as it 'trims' the image perfectly in every case.

Answer (score 11):

It looks like the image is larger than the screen width, so it's getting scaled down after sizing. Try adding `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to your `ImageView`.

Answer (score -1):

you might want to add it your image view only this.
It fixed my problem.

```
android:paddingVertical="0dp"
android:paddingHorizontal="0dp"
```